# Freshly created logical volumes show large usage

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm

I created a couple of logical volumes of around 2.0G size for practice and then created GFS2 file systems in these.

There are eight physical volumes from which two logical volumes have been created.

```
# vgs
  VG    #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  IACVG   8   2   0 wz--n- 7.46g 3.46g
```

Each logical volume is of 2.0 GB size.

```
# lvs
  LV     VG    Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  IACLV1 IACVG -wi-ao---- 2.00g                                                    
  IACLV2 IACVG -wi-ao---- 2.00g 


# mkfs.gfs2 -t IACcluster:IAClock1 -p lock_nolock -j 4 /dev/IACVG/IACLV1
# mkfs.gfs2 -t IACcluster:IAClock2 -p lock_nolock -j 4 /dev/IACVG/IACLV2
```

Then I mounted the volumes.

```
# mount /dev/IACVG/IACLV1 /mnt/lv1
# mount /dev/IACVG/IACLV2 /mnt/lv2
```

However, these volumes are showing large usages though I have not written anything in these.

```
# df -h
.................
/dev/mapper/IACVG-IACLV1  2.0G  518M  1.5G  26% /mnt/lv1
/dev/mapper/IACVG-IACLV2  2.0G  518M  1.5G  26% /mnt/lv2
```

I fail to get an explanation for this.

Comment: The default size for the GFS2 journal is 128 MiB. You requested four journals. That's 512 MiB right there.

Comment: @AlexP Do you want to convert your comment to an answer which I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default size for the GFS2 journal is 128 MiB. You requested four journals (`-j 4`). That's 512 MiB right there.